# How to connect two virtual machines (Windows & Ubuntu) on VMWare?

Tags: networking, virtual, vmware

I am trying to connect two virtual machines Ubuntu and Windows (the host is Windows) on VMWare Workstation to test the sending of Mosquitto messages (MQTT) between the two machines, but I am a novice in network art. So I have no idea on how to proceed. I have tried to set an IP adress to each machine with the option "Custom virtual network" but it's not working...
Please help me on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Can a each VM ping the other one?

Answer (score 0):

I finally could make it work :

1. The two machines have to be connected with NAT
2. The Windows firewall has to be disabled
3. The IP address of the subscribed machine has to be specified in the mosquitto line command when testing the sending of MQTT messages between the two machines.

   ```
   mosquitto_pub -h [IP address] -t test -l
   ```

If not, mosquitto send messages to the local host by default.